# QueueTrigger Bindings for Sendgrid -Python

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, azure-function-app, queuetrigger

Guided by this [post](https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples/blob/master/v1functions/queue-trigger-sendgrid/function/function.json.example) I have written the following queuetrigger code intended to send emails when a message is queued.

```
import logging
import sendgrid
import azure.functions as func
import os
def main(msg: func.QueueMessage) -> None:
    logging.info('Python queue trigger function processed a queue item: %s',
                 msg.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
    
   
    data = {
        "personalizations": [
          {
            "to": [
              {
                "email": "rrrrrrrr"
              }
            ],
            "subject": "Sending with SendGrid is Fun"
          }
        ],
        "from": {
          "email": "ghyu"
        },
        "content": [
          {
            "type": "text/plain",
            "value": "and easy to do anywhere, even with Python"
          }
         ]
    }
    print('Sending email using SendGrid:', data)
    with open(os.environ[_AZURE_FUNCTION_SENDGRID_OUTPUT_ENV_NAME], 'wb') as f:
      json.dump(data,f)
```

**function.json**

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "msg",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "outqueue1",
      "connection": "storageaccountautom92bb_STORAGE"
    },
    
    {
      
      "name": "outputMessage",
      "type": "sendGrid",
      "from": "ghyu",
      "apiKey": "MY_SENDGRID_API_KEY",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

**local.settings.json**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "hjk",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "storageaccountautom92bb_STORAGE": "hjk",
    "MY_SENDGRID_API_KEY": "tyhuE",
    "_AZURE_FUNCTION_SENDGRID_OUTPUT_ENV_NAME" : "GIS klop",
    "_AZURE_FUNCTION_QUEUE_INPUT_ENV_NAME" : "msg"
  }
}
```

Whereas the function responds to messages as they queue, it is not able to send emails. It throws an error;

```
the following parameters are declared in function.json but not in Python: {'outputMessage'}
```

1. How best can I resolve this?
2. Are the outward bindings correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Function banned the port of send email, so we must use sendgrid to send email.(This is a third part tools but it was been integrated into azure functions binding, so we can directly use it.)

For example, if you want to send email from email A to email B.

First, go to the [sendgrid website](https://mc.sendgrid.com/senders), create a sender and verify the email A:

[image]

After that, email A is ready to send emails by sendgrid.

Now we need to generate a SendGrid API key and copy and store the API key:(This will be filled in the Values section of local.settings.json as an environment variable to read.)

[image]

Then, you can use it to send emails:

**`host.json`**

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 3.1.0)"
  }
}
```

**`local.settings.json`**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=0730bowmanwindow;AccountKey=xxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "SendGrid_API_Key": "SG._-yYnhzER2SEbAvzOxSHnA.xxxxxx",
    "0730bowmanwindow_STORAGE": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=0730bowmanwindow;AccountKey=xxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
  }
}
```

**`function.json`**

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "msg",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "myqueue",
      "connection": "0730bowmanwindow_STORAGE"
    },
    {
      "type": "sendGrid",
      "name": "sendGridMessage",
      "direction": "out",
      "apiKey": "SendGrid_API_Key",
      "from": "emailA@emailA.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

`__init__.py`

```
import logging
import json
import azure.functions as func


def main(msg: func.QueueMessage, sendGridMessage: func.Out[str]) -> None:
    logging.info('Python queue trigger function processed a queue item: %s',
                 msg.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
    value = "Sent from Azure Functions"

    message = {
        "personalizations": [ {
          "to": [{
            "email": "emailB@emailB.com"
            }]}],
        "subject": "Azure Functions email with SendGrid",
        "content": [{
            "type": "text/plain",
            "value": value }]
    }
    sendGridMessage.set(json.dumps(message))
```

After that, I send a message to 'myqueue', and emailB get the email:

[image]

By the way, this can only guarantee successful delivery, because some mailboxes refuse to accept mail sent through sendgrid. In this case, you will still get a 200 response, but the recipient will not receive the mail.(In this case, the recipient needs to go to the mailbox settings to lift the relevant restrictions.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225137/discussion-between-wwnde-and-bowman-zhu).

Comment: you have a minute? Saw my earlier message?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65067323/retrieving-keyvault-secret-integrated-in-a-httptrigger-queuetrigger-python

Comment: @wwnde You still get the id instead of value?

Comment: Actually looks like nothing comes through, all it does is to state it succeeded, give the id and duration of response

Comment: What was your output on Friday?

Comment: @wwnde I can get the value with no problem after reference...

Comment: @wwnde I am not sure but I trying to troubleshooting

Comment: I will wait, because when I run it in azure I get `500 Internal Server Error`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65119379/acquire-keyvault-secret-within-a-httptrigger-and-use-it-to-acquire-info-to-be-ou

Comment: I have a queue trigger issue if you have a minute. Happy yo post question

Comment: @wwnde Ok, please tell the problem

Comment: I have a queue trigger, when I go into the queue and enter the message mannually in Azure it fires. Howver if I use a timertrigger to write message, it does not fire and execute

Comment: @wwnde message still in the queue?

Comment: No the message goes to queue-poison almost instantly whether I enter manually or write via python script

Comment: @wwnde If it is just a single queuetrigger, can it run independently? I guess these have problems in your queuetrigger.

Comment: @wwnde It looks like an error is handled after the message is received. Your function is trying to trigger through the message of the queue but encountered a problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227002/discussion-between-wwnde-and-bowman-zhu).