# Retrieving Keyvault Secret Integrated in a httptrigger/queuetrigger -Python

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I have successfully integrated a secret in a httptrigger. I need to retrieve and parse the secret in a python code.

The following piece of code returns the vault id and not the secret.

1. How do I get it to output a secret values?
2. Can the same be done for a queuetrigger?

Httptrigger

```
import logging
import os
import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    test = os.environ["testkeyvault"]
    return func.HttpResponse(
             "This" + test,
             status_code=200
        )
```

local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "testkeyvault": "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://jjjjj.vault.azure.net/secrets/AzureAuthUrl/xxxxxx)"
  }
}
```

function.json

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, please refer to my solution shown as below. And please notice the last screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get it to output a secret values?

1, create a secret, set the value, and get the 'secret identifier', set this `@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=<secret identifier>)` to the settings of your function app.

2, create a function app identity, and let the function identity access have the corresponding access policy to the keyvault.

> Can the same be done for a queuetrigger?

Yes, you can. Basically you can get it from the environment variable as what you do in httptrigger. The value stored in the configuration of the function app will be read as an in-app environment variable. If there is a keystore reference, as long as the reference is successful, the secret will be returned. Otherwise, the original url will be returned

Comment: how do I modify `return func.HttpResponse(test) )' to give me a string variable say 'k' which I can parse on in the code. tried `k=return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(test))` but just didnt work. Sorry not so familiar with the request module

Comment: @wwnde please wait.

Comment: @wwnde You want to return a string?

Comment: Yes, so that the string is input as password to a portal

Comment: @wwnde Where are you going to do the processing? Is it OK to get the response body from the response?

Comment: I can get it from the response. It will be a short process within the the function itself

Comment: @wwnde Since you can get it, what do you mean 'It will be a short process within the the function itself'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225303/discussion-between-wwnde-and-bowman-zhu).

Comment: The end game here is to parse the secret as a password to sign into a portal. The following works well if I am getting the secret from keyvault conventionally  (if not integrated in a function); `test= secret_client.get_secret("TestSecret")  \n gis = GIS("https://fghy.com", "yyyy", test)`. If integrated within the function as you have shown above, how do I extract `test` as a `string` to parse into the portal?

Comment: got a minutes to spare

Comment: do you have a minute? Happy to post question if needed

Comment: @wwnde Yes, I have.:)

Comment: opened chat room are you willing to join

Comment: @wwnde Hi, so what is your question?:)

Comment: I have a queue trigger that deposits message to another queue. It works except the message is not deposited to the out queue. I know the funtion works because it does what I need it to do. It writes onto GIS portals and I can see that. Do you have any bindings of queue trigger to queue?

Comment: still there or left?

Comment: @wwnde Try to know how to create a chat room. :) This is the room I created: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226272/2020-12-22

Answer (score 2):

For this problem, I test it in my side. You just need to deploy your function to azure, then it will work fine. If you run your function on local, it can't get the key vault.

After you deploy the function to azure, you also need to add it to application settings of your function app.
[image]

Also do not forget enable the "Identity" of your function app.
[image]

And then add access policy in keyvault to to allow your function can access the keyvault.
[image]

[image]

**By the way, it seems all of your steps are correct. So please notice all of the steps above will get the value of secret stored in my keyvault show as below screenshot.**
[image]
**So please check if you misunderstood the feature of get keyvault in azure function.**

Comment: The end game here is to parse the secret as a password to sign into a portal. The following works well if I am getting the secret from keyvault conventionally  (if not integrated in a function); `test= secret_client.get_secret("TestSecret")  \n gis = GIS("https://fghy.com", "yyyy", test)`. If integrated within the function as you have shown above, how do I extract `test` as a `string` to parse into the portal?

Comment: do you have a minute?

Comment: @wwnde Sorry for the delay, I have something else on hand but I will do some research on it later.

Comment: that will highly be appreciated. I need to retrieve and use the key within the function and not to have the secret  output at the very end. Happy to change to another trigger type if needed. From the following link, I got an impression functions are integrated with vault to make it easy to retrieve and use within function `https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/updates/azure-functions-key-vault-integration/`

Comment: Hi @wwnde After review your comments with Bowman, I'm a little confused about your question. If you want to get the string value from `return func.HttpResponse....`, I think Bowman has provide you [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTPhb.png). If you want to get the secret in your function again, you can do it easily by another `os.environ["testkeyvault"]`. So what's your requirement ? If neither of two is what you need, could you please create another post and provide more details of your requirement ?

Comment: could we have a chat maybe between us a solution can be found?. Three days and still stuck

Comment: @wwnde Yes, but I need to know your requirement. As I mentioned in last comment, I'm confused about your requirement because it seems your requirement has been implemented already.

Comment: @wwnde Could you please create another new post and describe what you want to implement detailly ?

Comment: maybe I just did not present it as required. What I need is to create a function, which acquires a key vault secret. Uses the key vault secret to log into a portal. Acquire some data and post that data into the http trigger body. I am happy to post a new question if you can help

Comment: Sure will post question and alert you

Comment: From what is discussed above, is it achievable?

Comment: @wwnde I think it is achievable, but I still want to know more details of your problem. And if I can't solve the problem, maybe other communities on stack overflow will help you for your new post.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65119379/acquire-keyvault-secret-within-a-httptrigger-and-use-it-to-acquire-info-to-be-ou

Comment: @wwnde Ok, I will check.

Comment: will appreciate

Comment: I have a queue trigger that deposits message to another queue. It works except the message is not deposited to the out queue. I know the funtion works because it does what I need it to do. It writes onto GIS portals and I can see that. Do you have any bindings of queue trigger to queue?